# How to get handle of file path that is locked

Tags: winapi

There is a file on mydesktop `parent.lock` which is a text file. I want the PIDs that are locking this file. So I managed to list out all handles in use. Code striked out below.

I want to use `CreateFile` to open `parent.lock` on my desktop to get a handle to it, as I don't know the process which has it open I cannot use `DuplicateHandle`. Is this possible?

`GetFullPathFinal` is not an option for me for a couple reasons. One being its only Vista+.

<s>I listed out all handles with `NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation....` and it returned 54000 handles (does this number sound right?)</s>

There is a file on mydesktop `parent.lock` which is a text file. I want the PIDs that are locking this file. But I am not able to figure out the file handle for the parent.lock file on my desktop.

This is how I enumerate handles:

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm"); 
var lib_ntdll = ctypes.open("ntdll.dll");
var lib_kernel32 = ctypes.open("kernel32.dll");

var STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL = 0xC0000023>>0;
var STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = 0xC0000004>>0;
var SystemHandleInformation = 16;

var UNICODE_STRING = new ctypes.StructType("UNICODE_STRING", [
{'Length': ctypes.unsigned_short}, //USHORT
{'MaximumLength': ctypes.unsigned_short}, //USHORT
{'Buffer': ctypes.jschar.ptr} ]); //PWSTR  

//https://github.com/tjguk/winsys/blob/5f11b308171382046ff0f67ef3129e47e9fee06c/random/file_handles.py#L100
var SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO = new ctypes.StructType('SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO', [ //typedef struct _TagHANDLEINFO
{'UniqueProcessId': ctypes.unsigned_short}, //USHORT dwPid; //UniqueProcessId
{'CreatorBackTraceIndex': ctypes.unsigned_short}, //USHORT CreatorBackTraceIndex; //CreatorBackTraceIndex
{'ObjectTypeIndex': ctypes.unsigned_long}, //BYTE ObjType; //ObjectTypeIndex UCHAR
{'HandleAttributes': ctypes.unsigned_long}, //BYTE HandleAttributes; //im not sure if byte should be unsigned_long, maybe unsigned_char //HandleAttributes UCHAR
{'HandleValue': ctypes.unsigned_short}, //USHORT HndlOffset; //HandleValue USHORT
{'Object': ctypes.void_t.ptr}, //DWORD dwKeObject; //Object PVOID
{'GrantedAccess': ctypes.unsigned_long} //ULONG GrantedAccess; //GrantedAccess ULONG
]); //HANDLEINFO, PHANDLEINFO;


var SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION = new ctypes.StructType('SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION', [
{'NumberOfHandles': ctypes.unsigned_long},
{'Handles': ctypes.ArrayType(SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO, 5)}
]);

var NtQuerySystemInformation = lib_ntdll.declare("NtQuerySystemInformation",
ctypes.winapi_abi,
ctypes.long, // return //NTSTATUS 
ctypes.int, // SystemInformationClass //SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS
ctypes.void_t.ptr, // SystemInformation //PVOID 
ctypes.unsigned_long, // SystemInformationLength //ULONG 
ctypes.unsigned_long.ptr); // ReturnLength //PULONG 

/* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
* HWND WINAPI FindWindow(
* __in_opt LPCTSTR lpClassName,
* __in_opt LPCTSTR lpWindowName
* );
*/
// NOT SUPPORTED BY WINXP so just doing this to test and then later will figure out how to get handle to path name then look in here
var GetFinalPathNameByHandle = lib_kernel32.declare('GetFinalPathNameByHandleW', ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.uint32_t, //DWORD
ctypes.unsigned_short, // HANDLE
ctypes.void_t.ptr, // LPTSTR
ctypes.uint32_t, // DWORD
ctypes.uint32_t // DWORD
);



function enumHandles() {
    var res = {};
    var _enumBufSize = new ctypes.unsigned_long(0x4000);
    var buffer = ctypes.char.array(_enumBufSize.value)();

    while (true) {
        var status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation, buffer,
            _enumBufSize, _enumBufSize.address());
        if (status == STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL || status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH) {
            buffer = ctypes.char.array(_enumBufSize.value)();
        } else break;
    }

    if (status < 0) return null;
    var proc = ctypes.cast(buffer.addressOfElement(0), SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION.ptr).contents;

    for (var i=0; i<proc.Handles.length; i++) {
        //console.log('i:', proc.Handles[i].HandleValue);
        //var nbuff = ctypes.jschar.array()(32); //nbuff.length == 32
        //var ret = GetFinalPathNameByHandle(proc.Handles[i].HandleValue, nbuff.address(), nbuff.length, 0);
        //console.log(nbuff.readString()); //always blank i have no idea why
      if (res[proc.Handles[i].HandleValue]) {
        res[proc.Handles[i].HandleValue].push(proc.Handles[i]);
        //console.error('multiple handlevalue occourance for handle value of ', res[proc.Handles[i].HandleValue])
      } else {
        res[proc.Handles[i].HandleValue] = [proc.Handles[i]]
      }
    }
    return res;
}

var allHandles = enumHandles();
console.log('enumHandles:', Object.keys(allHandles).length, allHandles);

lib_ntdll.close();
lib_kernel32.close();
```

Comment: What is a "handle for a file path"? Do you mean "directory"? Or a "file handle"? Or are you trying to retrieve the file path from a handle? I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. Whether your number sounds right or not depends on your particular system and what processes are being run at the time; it could easily be right, or just as easily be wrong. It's difficult to tell without a) the code you're using, and b) much more detailed information about your system than we have access to from here. What do Task Manager and Process Monitor tell you?

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite I added code and clarification. I need file handle please. To a text file on my desktop.

Comment: @Blagoh: Your edit DOES NOT answer Ken's questions at all.

Comment: This is *forbidden knowledge*.  Famously, the SysInternals' Handle utility displays this info.  It dynamically installs a device driver to get to the undocumented kernel handle table.  Whose structure is different for different Windows versions.  You could of course just run it and parse its redirected output.

Comment: This is hardly *forbidden knowledge*.  And there are other ways to get information about open handles without writing a kernel driver. SysInternals even wrote an article about it: [HOWTO: Enumerate handles](http://forum.sysinternals.com/howto-enumerate-handles_topic18892.html).

Comment: I edited it again, thanks for the input all. Basically please help me get handle to a locked file, whose path i do know, with `CreateFile`

Answer (score 4):

`NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation, ...)` returns an array of `SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION` items, not `SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO` items. See [Enumerating the processes referencing an object](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/f0ce82bf-84af-4e19-b90a-83fcb61faad7) and [HOWTO: Enumerate handles](http://forum.sysinternals.com/howto-enumerate-handles_topic18892.html).

If you already have an open `HANDLE` to a file/directory path, such as from `CreateFile()`, then you should already have the original path that was used to open the `HANDLE`.  To find other handles to the same path, you can:

1. loop through the array looking for all entries whose `Handle` field matches the `HANDLE` you already have, if you have one.
2. loop through the array looking for entries whose `ObjectTypeNumber` field is `HANDLE_TYPE_FILE`.  For each `Handle`, use `DuplicateHandle()` to make it accessible to your app's process space, then use either `NtQueryInformationFile(..., FileNameInformation)` or [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962.aspx) to query its path, which you can then compare to the path you are looking for (see [File handle operations demo](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppFileHandle-03c8ea0b)).

Comment: Thanks Remy. I edited it again. Going through 54k handles and calling GetFinalPathNameByHandle on each one was a thought but it was too intensive. I thought lets try to open the file and get the handle for that file that way, then look for that handle in the 54k handles. But the file was locked so I was having hard time opening file to get a handle to it.

Comment: If you can't open the file in read-only mode to get a handle, then comparing path strings is the only option.

Comment: Thanks Remy. How can I try opening in read only mode, can this be which flags should I pass to `CreateFile`?

Comment: `dwDesiredAccess=GENERIC_READ` and `dwShareMode=FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE`

Comment: Or set `dwDesiredAccess=0` instead.